# Render an image only when it'll visible

Tags: flutter, performance, dart

Can i render an imagens only it'll visuble in scrollview?

My app has an list view with many products, when I scrolling down many times the performance of my app is down (i'm using a lazy list), i guess it's becase there many imagens (from web) render up my screen.

I'm thinking to do something like it:

[image]

Comment: i think `builder` already does that for us.  like `Listview.builder`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I already think it, but i'm not understanding why the performance down when I scroll for many time.

Comment: Are you using `itemBuilder` with it instead of a child ? Let us know if your still having issues - I up voted your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `Listview.builder` with `itemBuilder` instead of a child

It will allow you to **only render what is on the screen** or what is **likely to be on scrolled** in the *very near future* - your performance will be considerably improved

- I recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qax_nOpgz7E&t=782s&ab_channel=Flutter) from the Flutter Team on this topic **(lazy load a big list view)** at flutter.io - if you'd like to go deeper into the topic

[image: Illustration of Listview.builder]

Comment: You could edit your other answer! If this is a suggestion, a comment is more than enough.

Comment: This is my new answer it's better

Comment: I saw the video you was posted, it really will help me! @Aristidios

Comment: No, now it's gone; Could you edit and bring down image size? or just delete image, it would be no problem, because the OP has already image showing the same.

Comment: @MarcosGianetti Your welcome amigo ; ) I'll put the link back - I didn't know if I could ^^ - you should Up Vote - Yeasin Sheikh - too his answer was right : )

Comment: I'll publish here and close the thread, now I know what I'll need do at my code, thanks      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qax_nOpgz7E&t=782s

Comment: I added it back : ) your welcome ! See you !

Answer (score 0):

use `.builder` when ever you can find.

Creates a scrollable, linear array of widgets that are created on demand.

This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.
for more follow [ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html)