# ListView.builder don't work inside a Column

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

When I put a ListView.builder or GridView.builder inside a Column my app performance was "dropping"

My code was like

```
Scafold(
   body:RefreshIndicator(
         onRefresh: () {
        return refreshUI(setState,);
      },
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
                itemCount: productListObj.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return InkWell(
                        onTap: (){
                          showDialog(context: context, builder: 
                            (BuildContext context){
                            return DetailsProducts(context,productListObj[index]);
                          });
                        },
                        child: cards(index)
                    );
                  })
            ), 
            //Other Widgets
         ]
      )
   )
)
```

The ListView is a image products list, when i scroll down a lot the fluidity was falling, hence I change to

```
Scafold(
   body:RefreshIndicator(
         onRefresh: () {
        return refreshUI(setState,);
      },
      child: 
        ListView.builder(
           controller: scrollController,
           itemCount: productListObj.length,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { 
           
           return 
             InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context){
                    return DetailsProducts(context,productListObj[index]);
                  });
                },
                child: cards(index, price)
            );
           }
       ), 
   )
)
```

However, now I don't have other Widgets below my list.

I don't understand why it's happening...

Comment: can you share full code

Comment: replace `column` widget with `ListView` widget.

Comment: can add also `cards` widget

Comment: @VickySalunkhe Replace column with ListView really helped. I noted when I was using only LitView.builder, like second code in thread, some imagens not found in back was realoding when I scroll up now it's not happing, i don't know if is good or bad, but the perfornance is good rsrs

Comment: you need to use a Expanded Widget wrapping the ListView one if you're using a Column. Do not use a SingleChildScrollView because you'll break the entire logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really suppose to use ListView with `SingleChildScrollView` & `Column` - it's kinda one or the other :

I thought it was clear in the video I shared with you [in the last post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68501180/12548494)

```
return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
  child: RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {
        return refreshUI(
          setState,
        );
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: productListObj.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return DetailsProducts(
                            context, productListObj[index]);
                      });
                },
                child: cards(index));
          })),
  //Other Widgets
),);
```